# Best way of grouping points into groups

Tags: optimization, data-analysis

I am given a finite set $S\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and a natural number $m$. Both $n,m$ are supposed to be small compared to $|S|$. Now I want to find the decomposition $S=\cup_{i=1}^m S_i$ such that $\max_{i=1}^m \max_{a,b\in S_i}||a-b||$ is minimal.

Here are my questions:

-Does this problem have a name?

-Are there methods to solve it efficiently, at least approximately?

-Where are these methods implemented?

Comment: With a slightly different target function, this would be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as minmax diameter clustering. You can find an example algorithm and background information in [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10898-018-0634-1).